# Liquibase causing java heap space fatal error

Tags: java, maven, memory, runtime-error, liquibase

the command i ran:

```
mvn liquibase:updateSQL -P MyProject -Dusername=MyUser -Dpassword=password 
-Ddb_name=$(DB_NAME) -Duser_password=$(USERPASSWORD) -Dvarchar=nvarchar 
-Dnumber=numeric -Dchar=nchar -Ddate=datetime -Dtimestamp=datetime 
-Dclob=nvarchar(max) -Dlong=nvarchar(max) -Dblob=varbinary(max) -Draw=varbinary 
-Dsysdate=GETDATE() -Dsubstring_function=substring -Dfrom_dual_clause= 
-Dconcat=+ -Disnull=isnull
```

this is my first time taking on a liquibase problem. here is the stack trace, how should I go about debugging this?
[image]

Comment: Please prefer posting text over images, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the  -Xmx  flag to a higher value. By default Java runs with a fixed amount of memory (64MB), which is too small for the program you are running (hence the OutOfMemoryError).